# PayPal - Express Checkout - is PayPal account required?

Tags: paypal

Does anyone know if a PayPal account is always required when using Express Checkout? My requirement is that buyers should be able to pay with credit card only.

Looking at the demo here: https://demo.paypal.com/gb/demo/home an account is required.

Maybe an account is required for the client-side only integration but not for the server side REST integration?

Any answer much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not necessary (but pay with paypal balance is much safe) because you can Pay with Credit card too. The setting of accepting guest checkout can be found here (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments)